# Want to parse Select autcomplete data on next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am preparing a script where user select 2 or more countries from auto complete text box and increment rows via add delete button, so when a user enters country name, it searches the country name from database and returns related information (country code, ISD code and Country no.) to respective textboxes.

Now the Issue is I want to parse those data select data on next page to show as selected Data.

One next page I want to show Information like below:

```
S No.           Country Name           Code            PhoneCode
1
2
so on...
```

I am new to AJAX and jQuery.

```js
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
 $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
 check();
});
var i=$('table tr').length;

$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 count=$('table tr').length;
 
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
    data +="<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='countryname_"+i+"' name='countryname[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='country_no_"+i+"' name='country_no[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='phone_code_"+i+"' name='phone_code[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='country_code_"+i+"' name='country_code[]'/></td></tr>";
 $('table').append(data);
 row = i ;
 $('#countryname_'+i).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_table',
      row_num : row
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[0],
      value: code[0],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
  id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");     
  $('#country_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
  $('#phone_code_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
  $('#country_code_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
 }         
  });
  
  $('#country_code_'+i).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_table',
      row_num : row
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[3],
      value: code[3],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");   
  $('#country_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
  $('#phone_code_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
  $('#countryname_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
 }         
  });
  $('#phone_code_'+i).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_table',
      row_num : row
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[2],
      value: code[2],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
  id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");      
  $('#country_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
  $('#country_code_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
  $('#countryname_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
 }         
  });
  $('#country_no_'+i).autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_table',
      row_num : row
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[1],
      value: code[1],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
  id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");      
  $('#country_code_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
  $('#phone_code_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
  $('#countryname_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
 }         
  });
  
 i++;
});
    
function select_all() {
 $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
  if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
   $(this).prop("checked", false); 
  } else {
   $(this).prop("checked", true); 
  } 
 });
}

function check(){
 obj=$('table tr').find('span');
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  id=value.id;
  $('#'+id).html(key+1);
 });
}
          
$('#countryname_1').autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
   url : 'ajax.php',
   dataType: "json",
   method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_table',
      row_num : 1
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[0],
      value: code[0],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
  });
 },
 autoFocus: true,        
 minLength: 0,
 select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");      
  $('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);
  $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
  $('#country_code_1').val(names[3]);
 }         
});
         
$('#country_code_1').autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_code',
      row_num : 1
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[3],
      value: code[3],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");     
  $('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);
  $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
  $('#countryname_1').val(names[0]);
 },
 open: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
 },
 close: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
 }         
 });
  
 $('#country_no_1').autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'country_no',
      row_num : 1
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[1],
      value: code[1],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");     
  $('#country_code_1 ').val(names[3]);
  $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
  $('#countryname_1').val(names[0]);
 },
 open: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
 },
 close: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
 }         
});
  
$('#phone_code_1').autocomplete({
   source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
     url : 'ajax.php',
     dataType: "json",
     method: 'post',
   data: {
      name_startsWith: request.term,
      type: 'phone_code',
      row_num : 1
   },
    success: function( data ) {
     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      var code = item.split("|");
     return {
      label: code[2],
      value: code[2],
      data : item
     }
    }));
   }
    });
   },
   autoFocus: true,        
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
  var names = ui.item.data.split("|");     
  $('#country_code_1 ').val(names[3]);
  $('#country_no_1 ').val(names[1]);
  $('#countryname_1').val(names[0]);
 },
 open: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
 },
 close: function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
 }         
});
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-top {
 min-height: 62px
}

.nav {
 font-family: Rokkitt, serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
 border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 line-height: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-top: 0
}

.navbar-inverse {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 border-top: 3px solid #91c448
}

.dropdown-menu {
 background-color: #fff
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover
 {
 background-color: #91c448;
 color: #fff
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle,.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus,.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover
 {
 background-color: #91c448;
 border-color: #91c448;
 color: #fff
}

footer {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 3% 1%;
}

.main-content {
 min-height: 480px;
 margin-top: 65px;
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 20px
}

h1 {
 font-family: Pacifico;
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #91c448
}
.form-control{
 border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="jquery autocomplete">
 <meta name="keywords" content="jquery autocomplete">
 <meta name="author" content="muni">
    <title>Country Selection</title>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  
 
   
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row main-content">        
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
       
          <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 50px;" class="text-center" >
           <h1> Select Country Name</h1> 
    </div>
    <form id='students' method='post' name='students' action='index.php'>
     <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
           <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
           <th>S. No</th>
           <th>Country Name</th>
           <th>Country Number</th>
           <th>Country Phone code</th>
           <th>Country code</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
           <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='countryname_1' name='countryname[]'/></td>
           <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='country_no_1' name='country_no[]'/></td>
           <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='phone_code_1' name='phone_code[]'/></td>
           <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='country_code_1' name='country_code[]'/> </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
      <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ Add More</button>
                      <input type="submit" value="NEXT" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div> 
   
  </div> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <script src="js/auto.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```